# i receive this message: 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'connect' ('connect' is my project name folder) when i run my server

Tags: django-views

This is the code on urls.py :

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from connect.account.views import index

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index),
]
```

And this is the message that i got:

```
PS C:\Users\Masse\Documents\formulaire> & C:/Users/Masse/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python.exe c:/Users/Masse/Documents/formulaire/connect/connect/urls.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Masse\Documents\formulaire\connect\connect\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    from connect.account.views import index
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'connect'
PS C:\Users\Masse\Documents\formulaire>
```

please help me !

I have watched a lot of tutoriels but it doesnt work

Comment: please post your folder structure